# Where is the subject in "as was traditional for unmarried women"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses, subjects, subordinate-clauses

My senior English teacher was a tad bit confused where the subject for *was* is in this sentence:

> As was traditional for unmarried women, Jane lived at home her entire life.

Comment: Good question, Tyler. I'd say your English teacher's confusion is quite justified considering the confusion among grammarians and the members of this forum AS CAN be observed in the answers to your question :)

Answer (score 12):

Strange as it may sound, the subject of "was" is, in the opinion of many renowned grammarians (please read N.B. below), the relative pronoun "as". In that sentence, "as" is not a conjunction but a relative word equivalent to sentential relative "which", but, unlike the latter, which always appears **after** the sentence to which it refers, "as" can **precede** the sentence, as a fronted non-restrictive relative clause:

- **As was** traditional for unmarried women, Jane lived at home her entire life.
- Jane lived at home her entire life, **as/which was** traditional for unmarried women (and **this**, i.e. living at home her entire life, was traditional for unmarried women). "as" substitutes for the whole preceding sentence and, for this reason, introduces a sentential relative clause.

N.B. Here is the evidence that accounts for my answer (sorry for the delay in finding it). Please note that I'm not saying that the answer I am giving is the only one possible -- quite on the contrary, I admitted in the comments below that there may be different views on this, as well as on other grammatical matters.

On page 126 of "Studies in English Language and Teaching: In Honor of Flor Aarts," under **2.2.1 *As* introducing finite clauses**, the author starts admitting how much controversy this question arouses. You can read the section in question [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=5ZCJCu_a3SYC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22as%20introducing%20finite%20clauses%22%20%20%22Studies%20in%20English%20Language%20and%20Teaching%22&source=bl&ots=RT9LJnLvNT&sig=0e_grL6wqbndcm3t2RXEvH40bmo&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjasoa4-JDSAhWCgZAKHcPXAzsQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22as%20introducing%20finite%20clauses%22%20%20%22Studies%20in%20English%20Language%20and%20Teaching%22&f=false). Then, the author mentions that Curme (1931:219) lists *as* with the relative pronouns and, later on, that Quirk *et al* (1985:1116) also claim that '*as* may function as a relative pronoun' in sentential relative clauses. Even Fowler refers to *as* as a relative pronoun in the First Classic Edition of his Dictionary of Modern English Usage (see [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=cicUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22as,%20relative%20pronoun%22%20a%20dictionary%20of%20modern%20english%20usage%20the%20classic%20first%20edition%22&source=bl&ots=KCt5r8iQE-&sig=B_7Ag5oN7FdGE_iNkJlAnPXJmgA&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpzteM-ZDSAhXBDJAKHe3uCH8Q6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22as%2C%20relative%20pronoun%22%20a%20dictionary%20of%20modern%20english%20usage%20the%20classic%20first%20edition%22&f=false)). (So far as for the refusal to recognize "as" as a relative pronoun.)

Now, Fowler goes even further when he claims [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=cicUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22failure%20to%20recognize%20that%20as%20is%20a%20relative%20pronoun%20sometimes%20produces%20mistakes%20of%20a%20different%20kind%22&source=bl&ots=KCt5r8jHA4&sig=apNQDj34c2cNtsP4BNbjyvSEUVk&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6geyr-ZDSAhWHj5AKHfANChMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22failure%20to%20recognize%20that%20as%20is%20a%20relative%20pronoun%20sometimes%20produces%20mistakes%20of%20a%20different%20kind%22&f=false) that 'failure to recognize that *as* is a relative pronoun sometimes produces mistakes...' **as** *?it (note the asterisk/question mark before "it") would be the case if we wrote "it" before "would be" in this last clause, or before "was" in the clause at issue (the result in the latter case would not be ungrammatical or dubious, but the clause would change its meaning to reason): "**As it was** traditional for unmarried women (to do so), Jane lived at home here entire life."

Final note: I do hope that those who cast a downvote take it back kindly disregarding my initial apparently unfounded opinion (based on literature I claimed to have read but did not have available at the time) and considering, in the face of the evidence provided, the opinion of the well-reputed grammarians cited. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide supporting evidence from a recognised work on grammar?

Comment: For a start, you may want to have a look at the quite similar example of "as" as a pronoun under 14. here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?r=66

Comment: "As" can never be a relative pronoun. The clause in question is an adjunct of comparison headed by the preposition "as". It is subjectless, but the subject is recoverable from the matrix and can be paraphrased as "Living at home one's entire life was traditional for unmarried women".

Comment: @sumelic Prepositions can never introduce clauses.

Comment: Call it a conjunction if you like, then.

Comment: @Gustavson Prepostions can take clauses as complement, and often do, for example  "I left **because I was tired**", "We agreed **on how to proceed**".

Comment: @BillJ I agree. What I meant to say is that prepositions alone cannot introduce clauses, while conjunctions and pronouns can. The structure above is composed by a preposition and a complement to that prepositon. It is the complement that is a clause. The preposition does not form part of it.

Comment: So you understand that "as" is not a relative pronoun and therefore no relative clause? The subject is understood as "Living at home one's entire life".

Comment: @BillJ I have read somewhere that "as" can be a sentence relative. I need to find it. It is remarkable that it can be replaced with "which" so easily, isn't it? However, I admit that your analysis is feasible and convincing, too. In grammar, and mainly in syntax, there is not always only one possible option, is there?

Comment: I think that the best analysis is as a shortening of 'Jane lived at home her entire life, conforming to the pattern that was traditional for unmarried women.' The _ING_-clause here is non-finite and does not have a subject, so why should one be expected for the further-shortened form.

Comment: @sumelic I appreciate it. The point Fowler makes about "it" being incorrect between "as" and a tensed form of "be" is really strong and makes "as" very special. The absence of "it" can then be explained by the presence of the pronoun "as" or, according to the other view presented here (which is also valid), as -- if I'm not mistaken -- the only case of a subjectless tensed verb (was, is, etc.) there is in the language. No doubt "as" is one the trickiest and most versatile words in English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is indeed a good paraphrase, but quite a few changes have been introduced. "conforming" is a non-finite and, just like other participial clauses, its subject is that of the main clause. In the dependent clause at issue, "was" is a finite verb, and that's a world of difference. Also notice that there must be something pronominal in "as" for you to need to resort to the noun phrase + relative clause "the pattern that was..."

Comment: I'm indicating that demand for a subject is not always warranted. Compare 'As is obvious, ...' with 'Obviously, ...'. Does it make sense to insist on a subject with these pragmatic markers ('adjuncts', as CGEL calls them)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, the opening question asked about the subject. Also, if everything comes does to pragmatics, then what's the use of syntax? I believe grammar is particularly useful to decide whether certain structures are correct or not, and even to decide if they mean the same thing or different things. Have you ever wondered why "as is obvious" and "as is usual" can be set off by a comma, while only "as usual" (not "as obvious") can? Syntax has the answer. Syntax can also explain the difference beween "as required", "as is/was required", and "as it is/was required".

Comment: In my comment above I made a typo. I meant to say "...if everything comes down to pragmatics..."

Comment: A new downvote again! It seems to me that some people feel so comfortable with their acquired knowledge that they won't even make an effort to see beyond.

Comment: @Araucaria I know. That was an addition of my own, based on the exact equivalence between "As was traditional for unmarried women, Jane lived at home her entire life" and "Jane lived at home her entire life, as was traditional for unmarried women" (Both clearly mean: This, Jane's living at home her entire life, was traditional for unmarried women.")

Comment: @Gustavson I agree about the equivalence - but I'd take that as evidence against Q et al's position here ...

Comment: @Araucaria I understand, but as you know pronouns can have anaphoric (backward) or cataphoric (forward) reference: "This was typical of her times: Jane lived at home her entire life" - "Jane lived at home her entire life: this was typical of her times."

Comment: @Gustavson Yes, that's true. But RC's, in English at any rate, only adjoin on one side - in the case of English, on the right-hand side! Still. Interesting post ...

Answer (score 11):

***As __ was traditional for unmarried women***, Jane lived at home her entire life.

It has no overt subject.

The expression in bold is an adjunct of comparison with the preposition "as" as head. The comparative clause functioning as complement to "as" is structurally incomplete as I've marked with __ to represent the missing subject, though it is recoverable from the matrix: what was traditional for unmarried women in those days was living at home.

Comment: The online OED appears(?) to adequately cover this scenario with [its **as** entry (last
updated in March 2021)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307#eid38319418)
in this way: « **B.** *conj.* **II.** Introducing a clause expressing
quality or manner. […] 9a. Introducing a clause modifying the whole main
clause or some part other than its predicate: in accordance with what (is);
in the way that. […] 2007 Roger Lovegrove *Silent Fields* vii. 193 —— As
was often the case, there is no record of the numbers taken.»

Answer (score 9):

The subject of "was" is apparently missing. This is a complex sentence, so not all parts have to have all the elements of a main clause. The main clause of the sentence is the second part, "Jane lived at home her entire life."

I found the following explanation in"[A Short Overview of English Syntax](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html) based on *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,*" by Rodney Huddleston:

> Comparative clauses generally function as Complement to the prepositions *as* and *than*:
>
> [59]
>
> - i   a. *I'm as ready as I ever will be.* b. ***As was expected***, Sue won easily.
> - ii   a. *More people came than I'd expected*. b. *He has more vices than he has virtues.*
>
> The distinctive property of such clauses is that they are structurally incomplete relative to main clauses: there are elements understood but not overtly expressed. In [ia] and [iia] there's a missing Complement and **in [ib] a missing Subject.** Even in [iib] there's a missing Dependent in the Object noun phrase, for the comparison is between how many vices he has and **how many** virtues he has. The fact that there's some kind of understood quantifier here is reflected in the fact that we can't insert an overt one: **He has more vices than he has ten virtues.*

(Some formatting adjustments made to emphasize the relevant example and to make the formatting work on this site)

[Gustavson's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/373696/77227) shows the controversy that there has been about the proper classification of "as" in this construction (conjunction, preposition or even relative pronoun). I don't know enough about syntax to explain the arguments for and against each position. The conjunction/preposition uncertainty is apparently based on the fact that traditionally, it seems all words that introduce a clause were considered to be conjunctions, but some current analyses (such as the one that Huddleston presents) consider it possible for prepositions to take clauses as a complement. There is a relevant footnote in the overview that I will quote:

> [7] In traditional grammar it is not *she left* but *before she left* that is analysed as a clause, with *before* being here a subordinating conjunction rather than a preposition. We present arguments in favour of our analysis on pp. 1011-14 and 129-30 respectively of [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* and *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*].

*As* certainly seems to function as a preposition in some commonly used constructions, such as "We're as good as them!" with objective "them" rather than subjective "they".