# Is the phrase "as I imagined would be the case" grammatically correct and why?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, syntactic-analysis

I had the following sentence in mind: *"The conflict escalated quite rapidly, **as I imagined/predicted would be the case**"*. To my ears, the sentence sounds good, and a moderate amount of people have already used the phrases [*"as I imagined would be the case"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+I+imagined+would+be+the+case%22) and [*"as I predicted would be the case"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as+I+predicted+would+be+the+case%22) before. However, I'm still concerned and not fully convinced about its grammaticality. Here are a few possible alternatives that should be "more grammatical" in my opinion:

- As I imagined/predicted the case to be [...]
- As I imagined/predicted that the case would be [...]
- As I imagined/predicted what the case would be like [...]
- As what I imagined/predicted the case would be like [...]
- As what I imagined/predicted that the case would be like [...]
- As what I imagined/predicted the case to be like [...]

Unfortunately, none of these alternatives returns significant hits in Google search, as I imagined would be the case (pun totally intended).

Is the phrase  "as I imagined would be the case" grammatically correct and why?

---

Answering to comments:

*Yes. That said, it's hard to explain why without having an argument to counter. Why do you think it's not grammatical?*

You imagine or predict *something*. So, according to this logic, the phrase should be answering the question I imagined/predicted *what*? I imagined/predicted what the case would be like. So now that I think of it, the most grammatical version of the phrase IMO should be "as I imagined/predicted what the case would be like, [...]", although it sounds quite convoluted to be honest. The phrase "as I imagined would be the case" omits *what*, *like* and inverts the relative order between *the case* and *would be*. Are all those changes grammatical?

---

What about the adverb *as*?

*As* describes an event by comparing it to *something* else. So a phrase that begins with *as* should be answering the question: as *what*? *As what I imagined/predicted that the case would be like*. That's the version that makes the most grammatical sense to me. But, of course, nobody uses it :-)

Comment: Yes. That said, it's hard to explain *why* without having an argument to counter. Why do you think it's not grammatical?

Comment: It's certainly a fixed phrase, and therefore kosher, but its internal structure is another matter. There should be a dummy _it_ around if Extraposition has applied, but it's not there. And _as_ is a very problematic particle.

Comment: 'The conflict escalated quite rapidly, as I imagined/predicted would be the case' perhaps illustrates the incongruity better. But it can be considered as a deleted version of 'The conflict escalated quite rapidly; this state of affairs was as I imagined/predicted would be the case'.

Comment: There are a [surprising number of cases](https://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/verbs/inversion.html) where word order is inverted in English, although I can't see this particular one discussed anywhere

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin - arguments against the grammaticality of the phrase added in.

Comment: @JohnLawler The online OED appears(?) to adequately cover this scenario with [its **as** entry (last
updated in March 2021)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307#eid38319418)
in this way: « **B.** *conj.* **II.** Introducing a clause expressing
quality or manner. […] 9a. Introducing a clause modifying the whole main
clause or some part other than its predicate: in accordance with what (is);
in the way that. […] 2007 Roger Lovegrove *Silent Fields* vii. 193 —— As
was often the case, there is no record of the numbers taken.»

Comment: @tchrist it doesn't mention the specific syntax, but rather gives a number of more or less synonymous phrases. This is helpful, but I wouldn't call it "covering" the grammar points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. No, it would not be preferable or “more grammatical” to use “what” or “the case” as well as *as* in this context.

Here is a previous question with information about how the grammar of this type of clause can be analyzed: [Where is the subject in "as was traditional for unmarried women"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373692/where-is-the-subject-in-as-was-traditional-for-unmarried-women)