# What is the direct object of "I imagined" in the context "as I imagined would be the case"? (i.e. I imagined what?)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses, subordinate-clauses, direct-objects

In my previous question [Is the phrase “as I imagined would be the case” grammatically correct and why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566146/is-the-phrase-as-i-imagined-would-be-the-case-grammatically-correct-and-why), someone referenced this other question: [Where is the subject in "as was traditional for unmarried women"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373692/where-is-the-subject-in-as-was-traditional-for-unmarried-women), which deals with missing subjects in sentences that start with *as*. That would account for "as would be the case". But what about "as **I imagined** would be the case"? What is the direct object of **I imagined**? I imagined **what**? I would appreciate a syntactic analysis of the phrase "as I imagined would be the case" to help me make grammatical sense of this and other similar complex sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'I imagined' does not have a direct object here, instead 'imagined' allows the clause that follows '___ would be the case' where there is a gap in the subject position. The whole construction headed by 'as' is usually a comparative adjunct in clause structure. E.g.

> *The team lost, as I imagined __ would be the case.*

This is discussed in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1147:

> [28]
>
> i [As I have already observed __ ,] no reason has yet been offered for
> this change.
>
> ii The event was sponsored, [as __ is the fashion these days,] by a
> brewery.
>
> iii He didn’t report the matter to the police [as you’d predicted __ ].
>
> The comparative clauses functioning as complement to *as* are
> structurally incomplete in that the clausal complements which their
> verbs would have in main clauses are missing. They are recoverable
> from the matrix: in [28i], for example, what I have already observed
> is that no reason has yet been offered for this change. Similarly in
> [ii]: what is the fashion these days is for comparable events to be
> sponsored by a brewery. Example [iii] is ambiguous: what you’d
> predicted may be that he would report the matter to the police or that
> he wouldn’t.

Answer (score 0):

In: "*[something] [happened] ... as I imagined (that) (it) would be the case.*"

"*as I imagined (that) (it) would be the case*" is a subordinate adverbial clause.

*"(that) (it) would be the case"* is the direct object of said clause, as you correctly guessed.

The fact that both (that) and (it) are elided changes nothing.